# how can i remove Product count after category name?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category

I want to remove product count from category in tree view.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move

**app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tree.php**

to:

**app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Category\Tree.php**

change code of _construct() like below:

```
protected $_withProductCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/category/tree.phtml');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
        $this->_withProductCount = false;
    }
```

You need to set `$this->_withProductCount = true;` to `$this->_withProductCount = false;`

**EDIT**

If you wnat to remove product count only from product category tab

Copy file

**app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Categories.php**

to

**app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Categories.php**

Edit code:

```
protected $_withProductCount;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('catalog/product/edit/categories.phtml');
         $this->_withProductCount = false;
    }
```

Comment: yes its work but i want to remove only product category tab. your code from all place to count like category menu.

Comment: Updated answer check it